# No se obtiene la línea exacta con file()

Tags: php, archivo, curl

Tengo el siguiente problema este código se supone que toma el primer elemento de un listado que se encuentra dentro de un `datos.txt` que contiene lo siguiente:

```
ph5986604c77db4
ph5988a83e37a80
ph5980f711d2b3b
ph5922205809bf2
ph593129a9631bb
ph5930d0950c8fa
ph5690ba39df654
ph593e778bc8219
```

intento obtener la primera linea de datos.txt usando **`file()`**

```
$fil = file('datos.txt');
$id = $fil[0];
```

luego uso `Curl` para obtener la página de esta manera:

```
$url = 'http://sitio.com/embed/'.$id;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0); //visualizar ñ y acentos.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate"); //(aceptación de codificación gzip)   
$response = curl_exec($ch); //almacena el response de la pagina.
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Pero no obtengo ningún resultado?

Mientras que si lo intento directamente de esta manera :

```
$url = 'http://sitio.com/embed/ph5986604c77db4';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0); //visualizar ñ y acentos.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate"); //(aceptación de codificación gzip)   
$response = curl_exec($ch); //almacena el response de la pagina.
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

S+i obtengo la página, por lo que me pregunto dónde estará la falla espero me puedan dar alguna idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función [**file()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file.php) devuelve un array con todas las líneas **incluyendo al salto de línea al final**. Es decir, estás obteniendo el valor `"ph5986604c77db4\n"` (con `\n` al final).

Para evitarlo, se le pasa la opción: `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`.

- Y, de paso, también usemos `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` para evitar líneas vacías.

```
$arrayLineas = file($ruta, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

if (!empty( $arrayLineas )) {
    $primeraLinea = $arrayLineas[0];
}
```

> Esto responde directamente a la pregunta y el error al usar `file()`. Para ver formas más eficientes de leer un archivo que no impliquen volcar el contenido entero en un array, pueden leer la [respuesta de A.Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/137356/127).

Answer (score 4):

Si solamente necesitas una línea de tu archivo o si el archivo es demasiado grande, creo que tu código no queda optimizado usando `file`.

- ¿Qué tal si el archivo tiene unos cuantos MB o GB? ¿Vas a guardar (si puedes) un archivo enorme en un array para luego usar el primer elemento o solamente algunos elementos?
- ¿Qué harás con los elementos restantes, traerlos para luego desecharlos?

Para leer una determinada fila de un archivo puedes buscar esa fila en específico. PHP tiene extensiones específicas para eso.

En este caso podría ser interesante la extensión `SplFileObject`<sup>1</sup>. Ésta tiene un método [`seek`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/splfileobject.seek.php) el cual:

> Mueve el apuntador interno [del archivo] a la línea especificada.

Puedes construir **tu propia función** para buscar líneas específicas de un archivo dado. Vamos a llamar a nuestra función `readFileByLine` (puedes llamarle de otro modo). Sería una función que podrías incorporar a una `Clase` utilitaria, es mucho más fácil de usar, sobre todo si necesitas hacer este tipo de operaciones en varias partes de tu aplicación, o en aplicaciones diversas.

Por ejemplo:

```
function readFileByLine($theFile, $theLine){
    /*Conviene establecer controles de la existencia del archivo*/
    
    $file = new SplFileObject($theFile);
    $file->seek($theLine);
    return $file->current();            
}
```

Ejemplos de uso de la función:

```
$theFile='datos.txt';

/*Primera línea*/
$lineaUno=readFileByLine($theFile,0);
echo $lineaUno;

/*Décima línea*/
$lineaDiez=readFileByLine($theFile,9);
echo $lineaDiez;
```

**NOTA:** La función se puede mejorar, verificando la existencia del archivo, la existencia de la línea que se busca, etc.

Si no quieres usar esta función, o si tu versión de PHP fuese anterior a la versión `5.0.1`, puedes hacer una función parecida que abra el archivo y mediante un `while`, busque la línea especificada.

---

Si la única línea que te interesa es la primera, puedes obtenerla también de esta manera:

```
$handle = fopen("error_log", "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) {      
    $lineaUno = fgets($handle);
    echo $lineaUno;
    fclose($handle);    
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> A partir de PHP 5.1.0

Comment: Muy buena opción.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta lastima que **readFileByLine()** da error pero encontré otra forma Gracias a tu respuesta  **$file = new SplFileObject($theFile);
$file->seek(0);
echo $file->current();**

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions ¿qué error da? Será que te equivocaste en algo o al pasar algún parámetro.  La función es lo mismo que el código que comentas. Solo que lo he puesto en una función para más utilidad y que es el tipo de funciones que podríamos tener en una clase utilitaria.

Comment: aparece indefinida la función **readFileByLine()** si uso tu codigo **$theFile='datos.txt';

/*Primera línea*/
$lineaUno=readFileByLine($theFile,0);
echo $lineaUno;**

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions es que no es una función de PHP, es una función que he creado yo. O sea, si creas la función, como indico en mi respuesta, podrás usarla luego. La idea sería incorporar esa función a una clase utilitaria propia que podrás usar con mayor facilidad en el caso de tener que realizar operaciones de este tipo en varias parte del programa. Quizá, como le di un nombre en inglés te has confundido pensando que se trata de una función propia de PHP :) Si la creas en el script actual y la pruebas, verás que funciona, pero debes crearla.

Comment: Bien igual lo intentare . gracias por tu aclaración

Comment: Muy buena aclaración me resulto muy util gracias por el dato